# Can't seem to connect to Win 7 share with smbclient 3.5.5 on Haiku

Tags: windows-7, networking, bash, samba, haiku

I did the registry mods mentioned [here](http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Windows7) but cannot seem to connect.  I say seem to, because there's no error message.

```
smbclient \\\\WIN7MACHINE\\ -U myusername
smbclient \\\\WIN7MACHINE\\ -U%
smbclient \\\\WIN7MACHINE\\
```

All of these, with or without quotes around the share name, (and optionally asking for a password, whether I enter the correct one or not) just return me back to the bash prompt without a further message, e.g.:

```
/> smbclient \\\\WIN7MACHINE\\ -U myusername
Enter myusername's password:
/>
```

What gives?  I can connect fine from XBMC.  Also, `smbclient -L \\win7.ip.address.here` lists all shares just fine.

If I get more specific than `\\\\WIN7MACHINE\\` I get this error:

```
session setup failed: SUCCESS - 0
```

...correct password or not, and dumped back to the bash prompt.

Comment: Did you try with smbclient //WIN7MACHINE/<shared> -U user ?

Comment: @dcrespe, I hadn't--the docs showed backslashes.